# PHP change only one value inside ini file

Tags: php, ini

I'm trying to rewrite a config.ini file which looks like this

```
dbhost=localhost
dbname=phonebook
dbuname=root
dbpass=
reinstall=2
```

I want to change the reinstall value to 1 like so

```
dbhost=localhost
dbname=phonebook
dbuname=root
dbpass=
reinstall=1
```

I already wrote some lines, yet i am stuck and don't know how to change only one value

```
    $filepath = 'config.ini';

            $data = @parse_ini_file("config.ini");;
            //update ini file, call function
            function update_ini_file($data, $filepath) {
              $content = "";
              //parse the ini file to get the sections
              //parse the ini file using default parse_ini_file() PHP function
              $parsed_ini = parse_ini_file($filepath, true);
              foreach($data as $section => $values){
                if($section === "submit"){
                  continue;
                }
                $content .= $section ."=". $values . "\n";
              }
              //write it into file
              if (!$handle = fopen($filepath, 'w')) {
                return false;
              }
              $success = fwrite($handle, $content);
              fclose($handle);
            }
            update_ini_file($data, $filepath);
            header('location: '.ROOT_PATH.'/');
```

Comment: So... what is your problem?

Comment: @xmastertje the problem is when i run this function it puts the same thing inside the config.ini, i need to change the reinstall=2 to reinstall=1

Comment: you need to check each value with the new ones. right now you just put the exact same stuff back in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it fixed like this

```
  $filepath = 'config.ini';

            $data = @parse_ini_file("config.ini");
             $data['reinstall']='1';
            //update ini file, call function
            function update_ini_file($data, $filepath) {
              $content = "";
              //parse the ini file to get the sections
              //parse the ini file using default parse_ini_file() PHP function
              $parsed_ini = parse_ini_file($filepath, true);
              foreach($data as $section => $values){
                if($section === "submit"){
                  continue;
                }
                $content .= $section ."=". $values . "\n";
              }
              //write it into file
              if (!$handle = fopen($filepath, 'w')) {
                return false;
              }
              $success = fwrite($handle, $content);
              fclose($handle);
            }
            update_ini_file($data, $filepath);
            header('location: '.ROOT_PATH.'/');
```